# How to export mysql to csv include all the table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv, export-to-csv

Following Code helps to export the **particular table** from mysql to CSV format..
But i need the code that helps to export to csv **with all the table** from mysql. Please anyone have the code. Please share it

```
 <?php
    $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'xxxx', 'yyyy') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('zzzz', $conn) or die(mysql_error($conn));

    $query = sprintf('SELECT * FROM TABLENAME');
    $result = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error($conn));      

    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=export.csv');

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    if ($row) {
        echocsv(array_keys($row));
    }     

    while ($row) {
        echocsv($row);
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    }

    function echocsv($fields)
    {
        $separator = '';
        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            if (preg_match('/\\r|\\n|,|"/', $field)) {
                $field = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $field) . '"';
            }
            echo $separator . $field;
            $separator = ',';
        }
        echo "\r\n";
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Have you considered a loop through `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code `SHOW TABLES` query returns the all tables in your selected db.

```
$tablesRes = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES',$conn);
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($tablesRes)){
    $tables[] = $row[0];
}

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=export.csv');

foreach($tables as $table){
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM '.$table;
    $result = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error($conn));
    //your csv code here
}
```